# Are there an standards for magnetic charging cable for USB-C type connectors?

Tags: usb-c, standards, magnet

I have a disproportionate number of problems related to my USB-C interfaces on my cellphones (dust/lint in the jack, excess wear and-tear causing me to have to change the USB connector on the phone. As a result I'm thinking I should try using magnetic connectors; see picture below.

For the sake of clarity, I only care about charging - I'm not worried about data (but having data is OK). When I look online, I see connectors that look similar to 3 types - round ones with a single center pin, round ones with about 7 pins in a row on the one side and 4 concentric rings on the other side (excluding the silver outside) and oval shaped ones which appear less common.

#### Are these connectors standardized, and if only partially standardized what should I look for other then the obvious form factor?

Relatedly, are there any specific characteristics I should be particularly mindful of when purchasing these cables?

[image]

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you mean by magnetic Type-C USB cables.

Comment: @ramhound - I may be using the wrong term for lack of knowing the correct one.  (I am aware that these connectors are, strictly speaking not USB-C as they won't match the spec).   The kinds of cables I'm talking about have an end that stays permanently in the phone, and the other end which is magnetic and can attach to a cable - https://www.amazon.com/usb-c-magnetic-cable/s?k=usb+c+magnetic+cable shows a whole lot of these kinds of cables.

Comment: No, there is no standard

Comment: @Ramhound I added a pic. The seem fishy. No declared standard and none made by a reputable company/brand. Stay away I say!

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - yeah, lack of standards and name-brands are a concern.  That said, I did personally know of 1 person - about 5 years ago - who had these and swore by them - so there are at least some that work in some cases.

Comment: There's nothing in the spec that allows for this as far as I know. Its a clever hack but I'd be a little weary of using it as say a 100v charging cable